# Checkboxes in a simple form are not displayed

Tags: 8, forms

I have a simple form in a custom module that works well and is displaying my select as it should.

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\efq\Form\FilterForm');
$form["container"] =  array(
    'categories' => array(
        '#title' => t('Select a Category'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' =>  array(
            1 => t('Option 1'),
            2 => t('Option 2'),
            3 => t('Option 3'),
        )
    )
);
```

I would like to change Select for Checkboxes. According to [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Checkboxes.php/class/Checkboxes/8.3.x), "Checkboxes" structure is the same as per "Select".
But when I change `'#type' => 'select'` for `'#type' => 'checkboxes'` there are no checkboxes created and I got the 2 following warnings:

```
Notice: Undefined index: #title_display in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Checkboxes::preRenderCompositeFormElement() (line 20 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/CompositeFormElementTrait.php).
Notice: Undefined index: #id in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Checkboxes::preRenderCompositeFormElement() (line 30 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/CompositeFormElementTrait.php).
```

Adding these in an array makes the notice messages disappear but the checkboxes are still not showing.

Any idea of what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

You code works for me. I used the exact following code and got checkboxes in my form using Drupal 8.3.4:

```
$form['container'] = [
  'categories' => [
    '#title' => t('Select a Category'),
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => [
      1 => t('Option 1'),
      2 => t('Option 2'),
      3 => t('Option 3'),
    ],
  ],
];

return $form;
```